# Работа с ТХТ файлом. Выбор данных из ТХТ

Tags: delphi

Из программы CUTTING я получаю файл с расширением ТХТ и содержит он след информацию:

```
 №    Длина   Координата   Примечание

 3      591     0           114-2012Т1Я1 Изд1 Пр2 Св
```

Константам относится (Т, Я, Изд, Пр, Св). Количество строк тоже меняется может быть и одна а может быть очень много.Мне нужно из этого файла получить второй (файл этикетку). 
 Такого типа:

```
114-2012    Т 1  Я 1  
Изд 1       Пр 2  
СВ         591     3
```

Теоретически я понимаю как сделать. 
 А вот практически, не знаю как начать. Очень хочется самому разобраться. 
Я пробовал сделать через StringGrid с выводом на печать - в TXТ файл в формате

```
114-2012    Т 1  Я 1  
Изд 1       Пр 2  
СВ         591     3
```

У меня не получается. Последовательность соблюдается. Но выводит в одну строчку.
Если есть у Вас возможность показать на небольшом примере как можно решить эту задачу.

Answer (score 1):

А символ перевода строки (код #13 или другой - смотрите справку) Вы отлавливаете? И по поводу печати: если у Вас готов файл-этикетка с, условно говоря, отформатированным файлом TXT (перенос строк - возврат каретки) - то под Win функция ShellExecute с параметром print - и все. P.S. У Вас Delphi, поэтому все элементарно решается.